# Javascript inheritance and Angular services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance

I am trying to create a generic service class that I can use in Controllers to get data. Here is my code:

```
appClasses.factory('baseService', function ($http, $q) {

var apiUrl = "http://localhost:1234/services/";

// instantiate initial object
var baseService = function () {
};
baseService.prototype.execute = function (webService, method, params) {
    params = typeof params !== "undefined" ? params : {};
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var response = $http({
        method: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        },
        url: apiUrl + webService + "/" + method
    });
    response.success(function (data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    });
    response.error(function (data) {
        alert('Error');
    });
    // Return the promise to the controller
    return deferred.promise;
};
return baseService;
```

});
Then in a module I use baseService to create module's specific service:

```
module.factory("moduleService", function (baseService) {
// create our new custom object that reuse the original object constructor
var alarmsService = function () {
    baseService.apply(this, arguments);
};
// reuse the original object prototype
moduleService.prototype = new baseService();

return moduleService;
```

});

Finally, here is how I use it in Controller:

```
module.controller('moduleController', function ($scope, moduleService) {
```

......

moduleService.prototype.execute("webservice_name.asmx", "webservice_method").then(result);

Everything works fine, but I am confused by a fact that I have to use a prototype to run "execute" function. Am I doing everything correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your factory to followings.. this way no longer need to use prototype any more to call base service method .

```
module.factory("moduleService", function (baseService) {
// create our new custom object that reuse the original object constructor
var alarmsService = function () {
    baseService.apply(this, arguments);
};
// reuse the original object prototype
alarmsService.prototype = new baseService();

return new alarmsService();
```

Comment: Yes, that helped. Thanks a lot.